# Fastlane + Jenkins on other computer: How connect them

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, fastlane

We want to start automating flows, CI/CD.
We have a Jenkins server running on a separate computer.
I don't quite understand how jenkins can trigger fastlane if it is running in another computer.

In the docs, jenkins runs locally where the lanes are, so I understand that jenkins can run lanes. But is it possible if jenkins run on a separate computer?

What to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

1. Remote execute commands in the instance where `Fastlane` is installed. For this, you can use something like `SSH Steps` in a declarative pipeline. Read more [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/).
2. Add the instance with `Fastlane` as a Jenkins `Agent.` Once you add the instance as a [Agent](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/) You can label the `Agent` and only execute specific Jobs on that Agent.